# make mouse move with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I am developing a page where certain elements trigger a hover-over box to appear under them. There is also a condition which checks if all the hover-box is in the view port and scrolls down if it exceeds the view port. The problem is that when it scrolls down the mouse remains in the same position, so the element is no longer being hovered over, so the box disappears,causing the page to automatically scroll back to the original place, so now it is being hovered over again, and it get caught in this cycle, which you can see is demonstrated in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HNkB/). Just hover over the inputs and you'll see what I mean. What I need is for the mouse to move down by the same amount as the page scrolls down. But you can not force a mouse move in javascript. So I don't know how to tackle this problem. If anyone has any Ideas, please let me know, or adapt the jsFiddle. Thank you. And here is the javascript:

```
$('input').mouseout(function(){
  $('#box').hide();
});
$('input').mouseover(function(e){

 element = e.target

 eleTop =  $(element).offset().top + 27;
 eleLeft = $(element).offset().left;

 $('#box').css({

    top: eleTop + "px",
    left: eleLeft + "px",
});

 $('#box').show();

if($('#box').offset().top + $('#box').height() + 27 > ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight)){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop:10 + $(window).scrollTop() + 
     ($('#box').offset().top + $('#box').height() + 27) - 
     ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight)});

   }
});
```

Comment: You can't move a user's mouse using JavaScript.  You'll need a different solution.  Not to mention, moving a user's cursor is a usability concern.

Comment: Even if you could get this working, I think it's a usability issue.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/mCpL2/  I can't think of a good way for this to work.

Comment: Try to open the hover box to the top of the element, if it doesnt fit below it.
Or let your user use the mousewheel or scrollbars, if there is more content below, but what you plan is no good for the user, as John stated before me.